# Regex to match a specific string but only if it doesn't begin with a hashtag

Tags: regex

How can I match a specific standalone term but only if it doesn't begin with special characters, specifically “#” or "."

Here is my current regular expression to match standalone terms

```
(?i)\b(two three)\b
```

Problem: Checking for boundaries does not seem to consider special characters.

Examples

- "one #two three check" ✘ Matching, but should not match
- "one#two three check" ✘ Matching, but should not match
- "one .two three check" ✘ Matching, but should not match
- "one two three check" ✓ Matching correctly
- "onetwo three check"  ✓ Not matching. Which is also correct

How can ensure that my pattern is **not** matching if it is prefaced with characters like “#” and “.”? I'd rather black list special characters than white list the alphabet/number as this should also work well for non-latin languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative lookbehind to fail the match if search term is preceded by `#` or `.`:

```
(?i)(?<![#.])\b(two three)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dM8dZ6/1)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to match a given string at the beginning of a word?  No need to get fancy, just match beginning-of-a-line | whitespace, then your capturing parens.

```
`(^|[[:space:]])(two three)\b`
```